# search by date-range in report viewer not displaying the right date range

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datetimepicker, reportviewer, date-range

I am using Visual Studio. Here's the case: In my report viewer, I have 2 labels (named from and to), 2 date time picker (named start and end with the format of dd/MM/yyyy) and 1 button, when the user inputs start and end date (e.g. 2011-2013), the report viewer should display all the entries within that date range upon clicking the button. The problem is the report viewer displays records from 2011-2016.

Here's my code in .cs:

```
`private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.tbl_descTableAdapter01.Fill(this.dataSet5.tbl_desc,
    start.Value.ToShortDateString(), end.Value.ToShortDateString());
    this.reportViewer2.RefreshReport();
}`
```

And here's my query:

```
SELECT Property_ID, Description, Acq_Date, Est_Life, Resp_Center, Acquisition_Cost, Acc_Depreciation, NetBookValue, Coop, Remarks, Type, Gender, Accounting_Officer, Status FROM tbl_desc WHERE (Acq_Date BETWEEN @from AND @to)
```

Comment: If my guess is not wrong your code is getting the value of `@from` and `@to` which is a label and not the value of `start` and `end` which is the date time picker. Are the values of your date time picker converted into string that is shown in `from` and `to` label?

Comment: Please, show your query code.

Comment: @P.Pat I have thought of the same thing but when I changed `@from and @to` into `@start and @end` (which is the date time picker) in my query, nothing has changed. I really don't have any clue on this.

Comment: You can try placing your query inside `button1_Click_1` and change `(Acq_Date BETWEEN @from AND @to)` to `Acq_Date BETWEEN ' " + start+" ' AND ' " + end+" '` and test if it shows the desired result.

Comment: I have tried placing that query inside `button1_Click_1` but it displayed the same result. :(

Comment: `private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tbl_descTableAdapter01.Fill(this.dataSet5.tbl_desc,
        start.Value, end.Value);
        this.reportViewer2.RefreshReport();
    }`

This worked!